# Why does function modify array[0] but not string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

**Code**

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declaring and initializing String variable 'str' with value "outside"
        String str = "main";

        //declaring and initializing Array 'array' with values
        String [] array = {"main"};

        //printing values of str and array[0]
        System.out.println("str : " + str + " , array[0] : " + array[0]);

        //calling function foo()
        foo(str, array);

        //printing values after calling function foo()
        System.out.println("str : " + str + " , array[0] : " + array[0]);
    }

    static void foo(String str, String[] array){
        str = "foo";
        array[0] = "foo";
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
str : main , array[0] : main  
str : main , array[0] : foo
```

**Question**

Why does the string `str` remains same as "main" but the value of `array[0]` gets modified from "main" to "foo" after calling the function `foo()`? Shouldn't the effect be the same?

Comment: The string literal cannot be changed by your method, as it's passed by value as a string literal, but the array can as the value passed for that array is its reference, so you can affect its contents via its reference.

Comment: Strings in Java must be immutable

Comment: You can't modify a String because it's an immutable object.    You're adviced to use a StringBuffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't, because of how Java deals with references.

You give your method two parameters: a String (that is, the address to a String) and an array (that is, the address to an array). These addresses are stored locally in `str` and `array`, if you change the addresses, the addresses outside the method (`str` and `array` of `main()`) won't change.

Then you create a String "foo" and assign it (or rather, its adress) to local `str`. This won't have any effect on str of main(). However, the array address is local, but what's inside the array is not. So if you would write

```
array = {"foo"};
```

that wouldn't affect `array` of `main()`, but with

```
array[0] = "foo";
```

you change something *inside* the array you've given as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

That is because Arrays have headers that point to the object in memory. Arrays are really just references to other places. So when you modify the array you are modifying the element 0 which points to an object in memory. When your method exits you have not modified the array[0] reference and thus you are pointing to the same spot in memory in which you changed the object at.

The String on the other hand, when you assign it "foo" are really just changing it in the method scope, because you are changing the pointer to a new string. You would have to return the string or re-assign it to the reference in the main method or you could make the string a field in which it will always have the same reference.

This link might help explain it better then me.

[Does Java pass by reference or pass by value?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you passed `str` as an argument for `foo`.  In java, when you pass any variable as an argument it becomes something new.  Making changes to `str` in the `foo` method will only change that `str` and not `main` `str`.

However for `array`, both variables are grabbing from the same data.  This happens because arrays are objects.  When an object is passed by value it makes a copy, but objects which are copied still reference the same data.

It is better explained here: [Java pass by reference or by value](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-by-value/)